# Using boost cpp_int for functions like pow() and rand()

Tags: c++, boost, pow

Need to store very large integers, so I'm using boost::multiprecision::cpp_int. Problem is, I can't figure out how to use this to get the values I want from other functions like pow() and rand() when using this new type.

I need to store a very large number that is calculated by exponentiation. But the pow() function itself cannot handle such large numbers and rand() returns basic integers.

More specifically, I simply need to store the value 2^1024 and generate a random number between 1 and 2^1024. But I've been really struggling to get this to work.

```
cpp_int x = pow(2,1024);
x = rand() % x + 1;
```

Stuff like this doesn't work for the reasons I stated above. I've also tried boost::multiprecision::pow, but that doesn't seem to work with cpp_int. What hoops do I need to jump through to make these relatively simple operations work with large integers?

Comment: See [the documentation for generating random numbers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/random.html) and [the documentation for integer operations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/gen_int.html).

Comment: I did actually see those before, but I noticed they use a different type "Integer", instead of cpp_int. Can boost.Integer also be used for huge numbers like cpp_int?

Comment: `Integer` is the template type parameter for the function templates. `cpp_int` meets the type requirements for `Integer`, and so the function templates can be used with values of type `cpp_int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [multiprecision version of pow](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/ref/number.html) (search for `pow` on that page), and then use a random number generator that supports generic operations, such as [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) (or the [C++11 standard random library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) that was heavily based on Boost.Random):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/random/random_device.hpp>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
int main()
{
    namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;
    mp::cpp_int x = mp::pow(mp::cpp_int(2), 1024);
    std::cout << x << "\n";

    boost::random::random_device gen;
    boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<mp::cpp_int> ui(1, x);

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        mp::cpp_int y = ui(gen);
        std::cout << y << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Live code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NjPozuGy1SFeXIsC)

Comment: The power function works, but the rest of that code compiles with 3 errors of "undefined reference to `boost::random::random_device::~random_device()'|"

Comment: I'm using code::blocks, by the way. Apparently this is a linking problem but I'm not sure what file I need to link

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out using a different random generator. Thanks for the help!